# Ubuntu 14 Vbox 4 install guest additions creates modprobe error

Tags: virtualbox

I am new to Ubuntu.   I am running Ubuntu 14 as host and Vbox 4 Windows XP SP3 as guest. when I boot my computer Acer E3-112 I get an error stating "Vblock client: Virtual Box Kernel service is not running. Exiting!"

this started after I installed Vbox additions.

Once the machine is up and running I open my vbox and all seems well except for the sharing of files from guest <-> Host.
Please Help.
-Trenton

Comment: The latest Virtualbox is 5.1.2.  Is there any special reason why you use 4?

Comment: It is what loaded when i installed Virtualbox ... can I upgrade to 5.1.2 without reloading the Windows operating systems and such?

Comment: Hmm.  If you want to use 5.1.2 you have to follow a different way to install Virtualbox.  You can keep your guest operating systems but you have to do a brand new virtualbox installation.  If you want to go through this, I can help but it'll take me a while to prepare a guide for you.

Comment: I typed incorrectly I only have the one Windows XP guest ... will I have to reinstall anything on the guest with your solution?

Comment: You will have to install the guest additions for the new virtualbox version only.  The rest of the guest system will be ok.

Comment: Your instructions would be great! would you also be able to point me to a good link for installing Windows guest on Ubuntu host ... there seems to be a lot of them out there and installing the additions I did not find easy.

Comment: sorry this came out wrong ... I am interested in the best instructions on how to load the additions. sorry

Comment: On the vbox website I could only find the version virtualbox-5.1_5.1.0-108711~Ubuntu~trusty_i386.deb .. is this the correct one?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to uninstall all currently installed virtualbox related packages. You can do this by typing `sudo apt-get purge virtualbox*` in a terminal window.  Right after that, you can follow this guide to install the latest Virtualbox:

1. Go to the official Virtualbox site: https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads and follow the instructions on how to add the official Oracle update server to your system and acquire the necessary keys.  The instructions you need are the ones concerning **Debian-based Linux distributions**.  Since you are using 14.04, you must replace *xenial* with *trusty* on this line:  `deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian xenial contrib`.  **Be very careful when adding this line to sources.list**.  If you feel unsure, copy the original file somewhere before you add this line at the end, so that you can restore it if something doesn't go as expected.  As for the keys required, it's easier to use the **combine downloading and registering** option.  After that, you can follow the instructions below and install **virtualbox-5.1**.
2. It is important to make sure that your username has been added to the **vboxusers** group after the installation is finished.  If it had been added by your previous installation, there's no need for you to do anything.  If not, you have to log off and back on for this membership to actually get activated.  You can check this by typing `cat /etc/group` in a terminal window.  You will see the **vboxusers** group at the end of the file and your username next to it.
3. Right after you finish **virtualbox-5.1** installation, go to this page:  https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads and download the **VirtualBox 5.1.2 Oracle VM VirtualBox Extension Pack**.  This will add *support for USB 2.0 and USB 3.0 devices, VirtualBox RDP and PXE boot for Intel cards* to your guest operating systems.  Right after you download the file, clicking (or double-clicking) on it will start Virtualbox automatically and it will install the pack.
4. You should be ready to use your new Virtualbox installation now and import your existing guest operating systems to it by selecting **Machine->Add** from the Virtualbox menus.
5. At this point you must install the new **Virtualbox guest additions** on the guest system.  Since your guest is Windows XP, there are two ways to install the additions.  If you want to use 3D acceleration on the guest and you have activated the corresponding option in the vm settings, you must boot Windows XP in **Safe mode** and install the guest additions in that mode, otherwise you can do the installation after you start Windows normally.  In both cases, the guest additions are installed by clicking on **Devices** on the host window menus and instructing virtualbox to insert the guest additions disk in the guest system.  The installation program will start automatically after that.

If everything went ok, your system should now be configured to check for updates on the Oracle server and update virtualbox automatically.  **Note** that every time an update is detected and installed, the first time you run the updated virtualbox, it will prompt you to update the **extension pack** too, which you should do in order to keep everything fully functional.  Also, after such an update, you should update the guest additions too the same way you did this time.

I hope this will help you update your Virtualbox installation successfully.
Good luck!  ;-)

P.S.  Since you cannot connect to https://www.virtualbox.org, I am pasting the instructions here:

**Debian-based Linux distributions**
Add the following line to your /etc/apt/sources.list:

```
deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian xenial contrib
```

According to your distribution, replace 'xenial' by 'vivid', 'utopic', 'trusty', 'raring', 'quantal', 'precise', 'lucid', 'jessie', 'wheezy', or 'squeeze'.

You can add keys with

```
sudo apt-key add oracle_vbox_2016.asc
sudo apt-key add oracle_vbox.asc
```

or combine downloading and registering:

```
wget -q https://www.virtualbox.org/download/oracle_vbox_2016.asc -O- | sudo apt-key add -
wget -q https://www.virtualbox.org/download/oracle_vbox.asc -O- | sudo apt-key add -
```

To install VirtualBox, do

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-5.1
```

Comment: Thanks so much for putting all this together for me!!!  However I am unable to connect to the Oracle site: https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads ... is there anywhere else I can go?

Comment: Can you connect to the main page?  https://www.virtualbox.org

Comment: No, and my network connection is fine .. i can get to other sites

Comment: I don't know any other official Oracle site unfortunately.

Comment: would this one work?        http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/server-storage/virtualbox/downloads/index.html

Comment: It doesn't contain 5.1.2.  Only 5.1.0.  And I don't see any instructions concerning the guide above.  Let me see if I can paste those instructions somewhere in here.

Comment: I updated my answer.

Comment: my email is tjoudekerk@bigpond.com in case you can email it to me. thanks

Comment: I just did the command:  'wget -q https://www.virtualbox.org/download/oracle_vbox_2016.asc -O- | sudo apt-key add -'   .... and it took a few minutes and came back with the following ... 'gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.'  .... what should I do?

Comment: I am going forward with the install ... I did the command 'cat /etc/group' ... and my username was not next to it ... I logged off and same ... I reset the computer and my username still does not show up ... what should I do?

Comment: It seems you cannot connect to virtualbox.org at all.  There is nothing I can do about this problem.  Maybe you should check with your ISP or something.  As for your username, it seems the first installation did not add it.  Unless the new installation is finished successfully, you won't find it there either.  You need to establish that connection to virtualbox.org if you want to continue.